# Repeat range of items multiple times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat

I want to repeat the range of items multiple times (Value provided).

e.g.

I have this in a **sheet1!A**

```
Detroit
Texas
Utah
California
```

Now I want to repeat them 3 times to get the output at **Sheet2!A** like:

```
Detroit
Texas
Utah
California 
Detroit
Texas
Utah
California 
Detroit
Texas
Utah
California
```

What should be the formula?

I got this formula:

https://www.excel-bytes.com/how-to-repeat-a-range-of-items-multiple-times-in-excel/

But it's not working in Google Sheets

Comment: The original formula worked fine for me - the only issue I had with it was that it had the wrong sort of double quotation marks and I had to edit those =IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(“Cities!A”&ROW(A2))),INDIRECT(“Repeat!A”&(ROWS($A$2:A2)-(COUNTA(Cities!A:A)-2))),Cities!A2)

Comment: @player0 [tag:spreadsheet] is for questions about spreadsheet apps that don't have an specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

this will work only if you paste it into **A5** of the **same sheet** and drag it down:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ROW(A1))),INDIRECT((ROWS($A$1:A4)-(COUNTA(A:A)-2))),A1)
```

[image]

otherwise, you can use:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A1:A4;Sheet1!A1:A4;Sheet1!A1:A4},"select *",0)
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A2,Sheet1!A3,Sheet1!A4&","),3),",",1))
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(Sheet1!A1&","&Sheet1!A2&","&Sheet1!A3&","&Sheet1!A4&",",3),",",1))
```

or:

```
function REPEAT(range,amount,header) {
  var output = [];

  // check if range is cell
  if(typeof range == 'string') {
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      output.push([range]);
    }
    return output;
  } else {
    // check if header is wanted
    var value;
    if(header == 1) {
      output.push(range[0]);
      value=header;
    } else if(header == "") {
      value=0;
    } else {
      value=0;
    }  
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      for(var j=value, jLen=range.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        output.push(range[j]);
      }
    }    
    return output;
  }  
}
```

---

```
=REPEAT(Sheet1!A1:A4,3,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create vertical arrays using array literals `{;}`. You can automate this process by creating a loop using `REDUCE`.

```
=LAMBDA(rg_to_repeat,times,
  REDUCE(
    rg_to_repeat,
    SEQUENCE(times-1),
    LAMBDA(a,c,{a;rg_to_repeat})
  )
)(A1:A4,4)
```

- First, we need to know the number of times we need to iterate/repeat. Excluding the first one, we have `times-1`.
- Then we use `SEQUENCE` to create a array sequence of numbers from 1 to 3(if `times` is 4)
- For each number in  the array, `REDUCE`, calls the provided `LAMBDA` function with the  `initial value` first and then the previous `a`ccumulator and the `c`urrent value, i.e., the number 1(2 and 3 in next iterations)
- For each iteration, the function joins the previous `a`ccumulator with the `r`an`g`e `to` `repeat`: `{a;rg_to_repeat}`

##### Advantage:

- Works even with 2D arrays.
- No string manipulation.
- Auto filling array formula.

##### Disadvantages:

- Newer functions have artificial limits on iteration and memory usage

Comment: Hi, can you explain it better? step by step?

Comment: @Griner Added better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I might as well add this as an answer:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Cities!A"&ROW(A2))),INDIRECT("Repeat!A"&(ROWS($A$2:A2)-(COUNTA(Cities!A:A)-2))),Cities!A2)
```

works fine in Google Sheets and Excel.

This also works and may be preferable in Excel to avoid the use of Indirect:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Cities!A:A,ROW(A2))),INDEX(Repeat!A:A,ROWS($A$2:A2)-(COUNTA(Cities!A:A)-2)),Cities!A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might copy down from Row1:

```
=offset(Sheet1!A$1,mod(row()-1,4),)
```

for as many sets of four as suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets keeps evolving...

Here's a formula that stacks / repeats a 4-row x 3-col array of cells to create a 48-row x 3-col array.

The KPI_LEVELS is a named range referencing the upper left corner of a 4-row x 3-col data table in another sheet.  The OFFSET / MOD 4  makes the array repeat the 4-row source array to reach the desired numbers of rows, 48 in this case:

```
=MAKEARRAY(48,3, LAMBDA (r,c, OFFSET(KPI_LEVELS, MOD(r-1,4), c)))
```