# Repeat A1:A4 n times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, repeat

I've searched and cant find the answer to this seemingly easy task

I'm looking to repeat A1:A4 n times

**A1:A4=**

> California
>
> Off
>
> Texas
>
> Off

**Desired output: n=4**

> California
>
> Off
>
> Texas
>
> Off
>
> California
>
> Off
>
> Texas
>
> Off
>
> California
>
> Off
>
> Texas
>
> Off
>
> California
>
> Off
>
> Texas
>
> Off

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73906610/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to repeat text in columns:

### **Solution 1:**

```
 =FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A4&";",B1),";"))))
```

Where **B1** is the number of the repetition.

### **Solution 2:**

You may also use `Join`

```
=transpose(split(rept(join(",",A1:A4)&",",4),","))
```

### **Solution 3:**

You can also use `TextJoin`

```
=FLATTEN(split(REPT(TEXTJOIN("^",TRUE,(A2:A),"^"),B2),"\^"))
```

### Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(A1:A4); FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT("@×"; 4); "×")))))
```

[image]

[image]

or see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266697/5632629